# How to get the extreme root directory of a storage in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently using "path_provider package" of Flutter for getting the desired directories.

But as far as I am aware about this package. It only provides path to specific directories like :
TempDirectory.
AppLibraryDirectory.
etc ......

But what if I want a custom path ..... like the extreme root directory of a storage.( Whose child will be internal memory an sdcard kindoff). How can I get the path of this directory ? I thought of hardcoding specific paths like this one manually in my project but then won't the names of the directories vary based on the device manufacturer ?

I thought getExternalStorageDirectory() function might provide me the extreme root of external storage. But it provided me with this instead.

"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.file_test/files".

when I wanted something like this : "/storage".

How can I do this ?

Thankyou for answering in advance.

Comment: You are not supposed to use that path. You can't even access most of it. The external storage directory path that you got is the place that you have read and write access to.

Comment: Thankyou for replying .......... But then how does the File Manager or Anti-Virus apps get access of those areas ?